# find image URL in a comment and convert to img tag

Tags: php, regex, image, replace

Is there a way to find an image source in a comment and convert it to an `img` tag?

I found this code to find an URL and convert it to a link:

```
$comment = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $comment);
```

But now I want to do the same for an image.

Like if I have the comment below:

```
This is an image http://localhost/website/image.gif
```

I want it to become

```
This is an image <img src="http://localhost/website/image.gif" />
```

Answer (score 2):

U need to find all URL's in comment and use it as link or image basing on extension:

```
$comment = "hi! its a link: http://www.google.com and this is image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg  and this is ftp link ftp://domain.com/file.zip";
echo $comment."<br>-------------------------------------<br>";

$m = preg_match_all( "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/", $comment, $match);

if ($m) {
    $links = $match[0];
    foreach($links as $link) {
        $extension = strtolower(trim(@end(explode(".",$link))));
        switch($extension) {
            case 'gif':
            case 'png':
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $comment = str_replace($link, '<img src="'.$link.'">', $comment);       
                break;
            default:
                $comment = str_replace($link, '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>', $comment);
                break;
        }
    }
}

echo $comment."<br><br>";
```

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/d3T1Xw

It's working with http, https, ftp, ftps